# is there a vibration dampener for a pancake box?

Tags: ceiling-fan, noise, vibration

I live in a relatively new house, about ten years old. The builder installed a fan in the downstairs living room using a pancake box mounted to a beam. Because of this, running the fan causes a loud hum and causes vibration in the floor upstairs above where the fan is installed. Is there a dampener I can install between the pancake box and the beam? I have tried multiple fans but all cause the same vibration hum do to the box being mounted to the beam.

Comment: Also, make sure that you've balanced the blades to get rid of any wobble.

Comment: Is this box actually fan-rated?

Answer (score 1):

Try placing a few rubber washers between the box and the beam with the mounting screws going through them. Some additional ones between the mounting screws and the box will also help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use bolt in dampers to isolate or dampen vibrations from motor driven equipment they look like a rubber slug with a 1/4-20 bolt out each end [mount](https://www.ebay.com/itm/293979322810?hash=item44728879ba:g:aRQAAOSwsRRgExpq) Not real expensive and they do quite some of the noise.